# Java stream use in loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I am quite new to java streams.  Do I need to re-create the stream each time in this loop or is there a better way to do this?  Creating the stream once and using the .noneMatch twice results in "stream already closed" exception.

```
for ( ItemSetNode itemSetNode : itemSetNodeList )
{
  Stream<Id> allUserNodesStream = allUserNodes.stream().map( n -> n.getNodeId() );

  Id nodeId = itemSetNode.getNodeId();
  //if none of the user node ids match the node id, the user is missing the node
  if ( allUserNodesStream.noneMatch( userNode -> userNode.compareTo( nodeId ) == 0 ) )
  {
    isUserMissingNode = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: This seems like a less than optimal situation to use streams at all. I'd use a `TreeSet` (as `Id` seems to implement `Comparable`) or a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use a treeset? You'd iterate through the collection and turn it into a treeset and then use a set.contains()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you make a list of all the user ids outside the loop. Just make sure the class `Id` overrides `equals()` function.

```
List<Id> allUsersIds = allUserNodes.stream().map(n -> n.getNodeId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (ItemSetNode itemSetNode : itemSetNodeList)
{
    Id nodeId = itemSetNode.getNodeId();

    if (!allUsersIds.contains(nodeId))
    {
        isUserMissingNode = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminal operations of a Stream such as `noneMatch()` close the Stream and make it so not reusable again.
If you need to reuse this Stream :

```
Stream<Id> allUserNodesStream = allUserNodes.stream().map( n -> n.getNodeId() );
```

just move it into a method :

```
public Stream<Id> getAllUserNodesStream(){
   return allUserNodes.stream().map( n -> n.getNodeId());
}
```

and invoke it as you need it to create it :

```
if (getAllUserNodesStream().noneMatch( userNode -> userNode.compareTo( nodeId ) == 0 ))
```

Now remember that Streams become loops in the byte code after compilation.
Performing multiple times the same loop *may* not be desirable.  So you should consider this point before instantiating multiple times the same stream.

---

As alternative to create multiple streams to detect match with nodeId :

```
if (allUserNodesStream.noneMatch( userNode -> userNode.compareTo( nodeId ) == 0 ) ) {
  isUserMissingNode = true;
  break;
}
```

use rather a structure of type `Set` that contains all `id` of `allUserNodes` :

```
if (idsFromUserNodes.contains(nodeId)){
  isUserMissingNode = true;
  break;
}
```

It will make the logic more simple and the performance better.
Of course it supposes that `compareTo()` be consistent with `equals()` but it is strongly recommended (though not required).

Comment: streaming *again* for each element... also a `Supplier` would more suited than a method. And while you are answering this, you could also provide may be a non-stream way that does not do so much work

Comment: Unless `allUserNodes` can change while looping, there's no reason to execute the lambda multiple times.

Comment: @Eugene I updated with a Set that makes more sense here I think. About `supplier`, why would it more suited ? I am not sure to get it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be equivalent, except that the value of the boolean is reversed so it's `false` if there are missing nodes.

First all the user node Ids are collected to a `TreeSet` (if `Id` implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` you should use a `HashSet`). Then we stream `itemSetNodeList` to see if all those nodeIds are contained in the set.

```
TreeSet<Id> all = allUserNodes
                        .stream()
                        .map(n -> n.getNodeId())
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

boolean isAllNodes = itemSetNodeList
                        .stream()
                        .allMatch(n -> all.contains(n.getNodeId()));
```

There are many ways to write equivalent (at least to outside eyes) code, this uses a `Set` to improve the lookup so we don't need to keep iterating the `allUserNodes` collection constantly.

You want to *avoid* using a stream in a loop, because that will turn your algorithm into `O(n²)` when you're doing a linear loop and a linear stream operation inside it. This approach is `O(n log n)`, for the linear stream operation and `O(log n)` `TreeSet` lookup. With a `HashSet` this goes down to just `O(n)`, not that it matters much unless you're dealing with large amount of elements.

Comment: According to his code (there is break for true), he doesn't need allMatch.

Comment: @egorlitvinenko that's because I flipped the (code) logic. The logic is "is each itemSetNode is contained in allUserNodes?", which is actually clearer in the inverted logic version.

Answer (score 1):

You also could do something like this:

```
Set<Id> allUserNodeIds = allUserNodes.stream()
    .map(ItemSetNode::getNodeId)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
return itemSetNodeList.stream()
    .anyMatch(n -> !allUserNodeIds.contains(n.getNodeId())); // or firstMatch
```

Or even:

```
Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(new YourComparator()));
```

Comment: Here the logic fails. You return true if even one of `itemSetNodeList` exists in `allUserNodes`. Not if even one of `itemSetNodeList` **doesn't** exist in `allUserNodes`.

Comment: I'm reversed condition of the author. "None match of all elements if A" logically equals to "At least one match from elements if **not** A". And if you look more attentively, I return true even if one of itemSetNodeList **not** exists in allUserNodes.

Comment: Ah you're right I missed the negation. It's tricky when you start reversing the logic.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Readable negation in java streams is quite complex.

Comment: In production code, I prefer to use method references or constants with readable names for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

It will take each item from the itemSetNodeList and check it if present in the using the noneMatch(). If it is not present will get true returned. The anyMatch if atleast once item is not found will stop the search and return false. If all the item is found, we will return true.

```
Stream<Id> allUserNodesStream = allUserNodes.stream().map( n -> n.getNodeId() );
            boolean isUserMissing=itemSetNodeList.stream()
                            .anyMatch(n-> allUserNodes.stream().noneMatch(n));
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. More info can be found on the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)